# Cypress version 12.14.0 just cannot find command files with Typescript

Tags: automation, cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I am attempting to include custom commands in my Cypress tests using typescript. It just seems so difficult to get it to work. I have moved the files in various folders but it is simply a frustrating experience. It shouldn't be this hard. Here is the structure of my project: I am using version 12.14.0 of Cypress and Typescript

In my support folder, I have the following files

```
         cypress
              support
                e2e.ts
                index.d.ts.     // declare namespace Cypress with definitions of commands 
                accounts-cmd.ts  // has Cypress.Command.add(.....)
              fixtures
              tests // my tests are in here
                accounts.cy.ts  // uses custom command findByAccountsId(id: string)
```

```json
       //tsconfig.json
       types: ["cypress", "./support"]

      //cypress.config.ts
       supportFile: "./support/e2e.ts",
```

I have my a declaration in the index.d.ts called findAccountsById(id: string) which returns a Chainable from and axios call. It is defined like this

```js
    findByAccountId(id: string): Chainable<Response>;
```

In my accounts-cmd.ts I reference the index.d.ts

```js
    /// <reference path="./index.d.ts" />
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to put the reference in `includes: []` property of `tsconfig.json`.

See [cypress-real-world-app](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/cypress/tsconfig.json)

```js
{
  ...
  "include": ["./**/*.ts"],  // catches /cypress/support/index.d.ts
  ...
}
```

My understanding is that "types" key is for node modules, not your own types.

Comment: The solution you provided does not work. Even using **/**/ as the root does not work